# Append Html Tag into another div from diffrent page in js page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page call js and another page call index now i want to create a popup form field which is created from the js page and all the html elements comes into the div from another random page. on js page i jast want to show the form field . how do i do that?

```
    function popupscript(event) {
    let modal = document.createElement("div");
    modal.style.height = "500px";
    modal.style.width = "700px";
    modal.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    modal.style.position = "fixed";
    modal.style.left = "270px";
    modal.style.top = "100px";
    // modal.style.margin.left = "300px";
    let form = "<h1>HI</h1>"

    modal.innerHTML +="<h3>NO:</h3>";
    modal.innerHTML +="<form action='' method='POST'>";
    modal.innerHTML +="<label>";
    modal.innerHTML +="<input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Name' value=''>";
    modal.innerHTML +="</form>";
    body.append(modal);
}
```

i tried this js code and the output is bellow[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLWed.png)

Comment: How are js and index pages related to each other? Are the random pages coming from the same domain as js and index? And no, you can't append `<html>` element into a `div`, you'll need another browsing context, like `iframe`.

Comment: yes all are random page. and i don't want to use iframe i just want to show a form in my index page but all of the form will show or append or inharit from this js code which i given above!

Comment: Like said in the comment above, this is not possible. You've to rethink your presentation. Unless ... "_js page_" is actually a script file?

Comment: SO, now what should i do? What should you suggest me to do?

Comment: Include the scipt on index page, and create the content there ..? There are tons of alternatives, just enter "SPA" to your favorite searching engine.